# How to make TWebBrowser ignore accelerator chars of others controls?

Tags: delphi, browser, mshtml, twebbrowser

I have a TWebBrowser placed on a form with the designMode enabled.
Bellow the browser I have a close button with the Caption set to 'Clos&e'.
When I am editing the contents of a document inside the WebBrowser and I press the key E the button close is called.
It appears that it is treating TWebBrowser like other controls that don't handle keys and/or don't accept chars (e.g. TButton).

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Descend from TWebBrowser, override the `CN_CHAR` message handler, and return `0`.  Triggering the shortcut with `Alt+E` will still work.

```
type
  TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)
    procedure CNChar(var Message: TWMChar); message CN_CHAR;
  end;

...

procedure TWebBrowser.CNChar(var Message: TWMChar);
begin
  Message.Result := 0;
end;
```

Comment: It Worked, but I needed to change the MessageResult from 1 to 0. Tks

Comment: Yeah, if you have result :=1 then typing is not working. If you change result:=0 it works ..

Comment: Translation to C++ Builder - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62802874/how-to-ignore-accelerator-chars-in-twebbrowser-design-mode/