# How to ignore accelerator chars in TWebBrowser (design mode)

Tags: delphi, webbrowser-control, c++builder, twebbrowser

I have essentially the same problem like the one described in this question:

[How to make TWebBrowser ignore accelerator chars of others controls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2602239/how-to-make-twebbrowser-ignore-accelerator-chars-of-others-controls)

So the `TWebBrowser` is in design mode and accelerator keys from `TAction` are executing associated action.

The solution was:

```
type
  TWebBrowser = class(SHDocVw.TWebBrowser)
    procedure CNChar(var Message: TWMChar); message CN_CHAR;
  end;

...

procedure TWebBrowser.CNChar(var Message: TWMChar);
begin
  Message.Result := 0;
end;
```

I'd like to try the solution described in the above question but I'm having trouble translating that into C++ Builder code. How do I translate - and - are there other solutions without descending `TWebBrowser` and overriding `CNChar` procedure (maybe doing it in the `TForm` based event)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Translation to C++ Builder (credit to Remy Lebeau).

```
class TWebBrowser : public Shdocvw::TWebBrowser
{
private:
    MESSAGE void __fastcall CNChar(TWMChar &Message);

public:
    inline __fastcall virtual TWebBrowser(TComponent* AOwner) : Shdocvw::TWebBrowser(AOwner) { }

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP
    VCL_MESSAGE_HANDLER(CN_CHAR, TWMChar, CNChar);
END_MESSAGE_MAP(Shdocvw::TWebBrowser)
};

...

void __fastcall TWebBrowser::CNChar(TWMChar &Message)
{
    Message.Result = 0;
}
```